# Broken URL on MAC Local Install

Tags: css, navigation, sample-data

I have just installed 1.9.0.1 locally on my MAC.

My local url is http://jim.local.com and also matches the base urls in the phpAdmin panel.

I am getting errors for all of the urls other than the home page for example, navigation urls are broken.  For the nav it appears they should be pointing to jim.local.com/index.php/accessories.html for example but the hyperlinks are defaulting to jim.local.com/accessories.html and creating 404.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've told Magento you're using URL rewrites, but your web server doesn't have `mod_rewrite` (or the nginx equivalent) enabled.  Either setup your  web server to use the `mod_rewrite` rules in Magento's `.htaccess` file, or configure Magento to not use URL Rewrites in

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engine Optimization
```

Comment: Thanks! I made the change in the Magento Backend configuration and it seems like it is working.  There are still a few broken links here and there but most of them appear to be working.